# floating point on altera: arithmetic or dsp cores?

Tags: fixed, point, fpga, floating, intel-fpga

i want to perform some floating point operations on altera fpga, but as far i understand there are two options from IP catalog: DSP core and arithmetic fp core

what should i choose for some basic operations like add sub sqrt mult?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go for the arithmetic cores. I think a lot of IP's are reused but given different names based on implementation.

Comment: Thanks for both answers! I actually checked in more detail and the DSP option is called 'NIOS custom instructions' or something like that, so i guess it is the hardware support when programming NIOS in sw. Probably it can be used as a stand alone IP (?) but the arithmetic cores seem simpler ....

Comment: I am not sure what document are you referring too. I tend to work with Xilinx FPGAs so I am not that well versed with Altera. But what the other answer mentions is correct. You will utilize the DSP slices in the FPGA for a DSP core.  But based on the FPGA and project it may not matter as much especially for learning. As per my understanding the DSP IP can still be used as a stand alone IP without the NIOS.  If you want you can try both to see the difference. It should turn up in the synthesis report.

Answer (score 0):

DSP core will use whatever DSP resources your FPGA device has, freeing LUTs for other uses, and hopefully increasing the speed, as DSP have multipliers and adders already available on silicon. On the other hand, your design will be tied to your specific FPGA device and won't probably be portable to other architectures.

Arithmetic FP core, depending upon what the IP catalog actually gives, may result in a more device independent design, at the expense of not using the full power of your DSP blocks, if the IP catalog gives you a pre-synthesized core (i.e. one that are composed using primitive blocks in Altera). If the IP catalog gives you a high level code (unlikely), the synthesizer is still be able to implement part of this core using DSP blocks and result in a design with similar performance compared to the first option, but with a more portable source code.

If your FPGA has enough DSP blocks, I'd go for the DSP option.